# EC2 target group keeps deregistering target

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have an instance registered to a target group but at the end of the month it keeps deregisterring and I have to go in and register the instance to the instance group. This causes a 503 to be returned when a user tries to access the website. Any idea why it keeps getting deregistered? The instances are behind and ALB.